# How does Entity Framework know which migration to add?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying with the help of Entity Framework to set up this without having to deal with the code-related part of SQL.

I created a model and added a migration via package manager console and it all worked well it updated and created the table.

The thing I want to ask is how does the entity know which migration I want to add.

I used:

```
add-migration (and put here the name of the migration file)
```

But the thing I don't understand is how does it know which model I want for my table?

Or put it in other words if I would have 2 models before I did any migrations which model would get chosen?

Would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using `entity framework migrations` and got confused how it works. Here is the explanations:

***`Question:`*** *`But the thing I don't understand how does it know which model I want for my table?`*

> - If you look into your project folder there is the directory
>   `Migrations`. Inside it all the `migrations history logs` written
>   into.When we made any changes on data model, EF Core compares the current model against a snapshot of the old model to determine the
>   differences, and generates migration source files; the files can be
>   tracked in your project's source control like any other source file.
> - Once a new migration has been generated, it can be applied to a    database in various ways. EF Core records all applied migrations in a
>   special history table, allowing it to know which migrations have been
>   applied and which haven't

***`Question:`*** *`If I would have 2 models before I did any migrations which model would get chosen?`*

> - As said earlier, as it keep track previous migrations history, so in    your `old model` it compares the differences and overrite latest
>   changes that were not written on older files. This is how it works.

Hope above explanations guided you accordingly and redeem your confusions. You can also have a look on [official documents here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)